# React state not being updated in Jest while working in the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

When I click the button it increments the value by the amount written in the input, it works when I do that in the app but when I try to use Jest and first `fireEvent.change()` the value of an input to 10 and then `fireEvent.click()` on the button it doesnt increment it and the value stays at `0`.

Here is the error that Im getting:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

   Expected: 10
   Received: 0

     33 |     fireEvent.click(btnPlus);
     34 |
   > 35 |     expect(parseInt(val.textContent)).toBe(10);
        |                                       ^
     36 |   });
     37 | });
     38 |
```

Here is the test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
describe('Counter works', () => {
  let comp;
  let inp;
  let btnPlus;
  let val;
  beforeAll(() => {
    comp = render(<Counter />);
    inp = comp.getByTestId('inp');
    btnPlus = comp.getByTestId('btn-+');
    val = comp.getByTestId('counter-value');
  });

  it('Counter exists', () => {
    expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('Input works', () => {
    expect(inp.value).toBe('');

    fireEvent.change(inp, {
      target: {
        value: 10,
      },
    });

    expect(parseInt(inp.value)).toBe(10);

    fireEvent.click(btnPlus);

    expect(parseInt(val.textContent)).toBe(10);
  });
});
```

The general Counter file:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    count: 0,
    inpText: '',
  });
  const setNum = (num) => {
    setState((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        count: prev.count + num,
      };
    });
  };
  const setInp = (e) => {
    setState((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        inpText: e?.target.value,
      };
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1
        data-testid='counter-value'
        style={{
          color: 'white',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '45%',
          left: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%,-60%)',
        }}>
        {state.count}
      </h1>
      <div id='flex'>
        <Button setNum={setNum} plus='+' num={parseInt(state.inpText)} />
        <input data-testid='inp' value={state.inpText} onChange={setInp} />
        <Button setNum={setNum} plus='-' num={-parseInt(state.inpText)} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

And the Button:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button
      data-testid={`btn-${props.plus}`}
      onClick={() => {
        props.setNum(props.num);
      }}>
      {props.plus}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: You don't want to call `render(<Button />)` if you're testing the `Counter`. The `Button`s will be rendered as part of `Counter`'s render.

Comment: How do I reference the Button component inside of the Counter than? Can I just add the data-testid to a react component?

Comment: You simply access the buttons by their `data-testid`s: `btn--` & `btn-+`.

Comment: I updated the test file so that it takes the data-testid of the button from the Counter component but it didnt seem to change anything and Im getting the exact same error.

Comment: I also checked if the btnPlus exists by doing `expect(btnPlus).toBeTruthy()` and didnt get an error but it still doesnt increment the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest avoiding initial component setup in `beforeAll`/`beforeEach` functions. Each test case should run in isolation and not be affected by operations executed in other tests.

Instead, create a helper function with that logic and call it on every test.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Counter works', () => {
    let comp;
    let inp;
    let btnPlus;
    let val;
  
    const renderComponent = () => {
        comp = render(<Counter />);
        inp = comp.getByTestId('inp');
        btnPlus = comp.getByTestId('btn-+');
        val = comp.getByTestId('counter-value');
    }

    it('Counter exists', () => {
        renderComponent();
        expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    });
  
    it('Input works', () => {
        renderComponent();
        expect(inp.value).toBe('');
        fireEvent.change(inp, { target: { value: 10 } });
        expect(inp.value).toBe('10');
        fireEvent.click(btnPlus);
        expect(val.textContent).toBe('10');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked, but doesnt `beforeEach()` just do the same thing and call the function before each `it()` or `test()`?

Comment: Each test should run in isolation from the other tests, but in your original code you had the setup inside `beforeAll` which would set the component up for _all_ test cases. While you could use `beforeEach` instead for the setup, having the call to `renderComponent` on each test makes it more explicit and readable.